# Problem installing some packages

Tags: debian, apt, software-installation, dependencies

My command and errors:

```
root@berbidserver:~# sudo apt-get install libxml-parser-perl libpath-class-perl perl-modules screen rsync sudo e2fsprogs unzip subversion pure-ftpd libarchive-zip-perl libc6 libgcc1 git curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package libpath-class-perl is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libpath-class-perl' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package pure-ftpd
```

I used `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` to fix this issue but it didn't work out.

Comment: What distro and version is this?

Comment: No reason to use sudo if you're using the root account.

Comment: if you are using Ubuntu you can download it from here https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libpath-class-perl and for Debian https://packages.debian.org/jessie/all/libpath-class-perl/download

Comment: i use debian 8.2 64bit

Answer (score 3):

In the comments, you said you use Debian 8.2. Are you aware that as Debian 10 was released in July 2019, Debian 8 transitioned from being the `oldstable` distribution to `oldoldstable`?

You should check your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and any files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory if it exists. If you are not using release codenames (like `jessie` for Debian 8.x) but status codenames like `stable` or `oldstable`, and have not updated your `sources.list` in sync with Debian 8's status changes, you may be accidentally trying to install packages from a wrong Debian release, which is likely to cause dependency problems.

It is also possible that the Debian repository server you're using may have some problems of their own. Maybe try using another repository?

(Also note that since Debian 8 has been superseded twice now, regular Debian Security support is no longer available for it. Only limited Long Term Support is available until the end of June 2020. Please consider updating to a newer release.)

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's caused by an incomplete source.list (`/etc/apt/sources.list`).

Check your source.list, especially the following entries (suppose ubuntu14.04):

```
trusty-security  
trusty-updates  
trusty-backports  
trusty-proposed
```

source.list example:

```
deb http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse  
deb http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse  
deb http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse  
deb http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse  
deb http://cn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
```

**Then run `apt-get update` and retry.**